# How to test required but accidental functionality?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, interfaces

For example, let's say I write a container class, which supports 2 kinds of operations:

- insert(x): inserts an element
- get_all(): retrieves all previously inserted elements

Maybe it has some kind of hash set under the hood, or maybe an SQL database, doesn't matter.

It works, it's unit tested, everything's fine, but then I decide I want to retrieve the elements in a specific order, so that subsequent calls (with no new inserts in between) to get_all() produce the same output.

This is a **required** functionality, in the usual sense of the word.

But it's also an **accidental** functionality, in the sense that there's a good chance any 'reasonable' unit test would already pass, without any changes to the code, 'accidentally', because of implementation details.

It's clear how to implement this functionality. If I used a hash set, I should switch to an ordered data structure instead. If I used an SQL database, I should add an `order` column and an `ORDER BY` clause. The problem is, even if I don't do any of this, the unit test might pass, and when it does it does so consistently. A simple `SELECT * FROM SomeTable` will reliably return the elements in the order of insertion in most databases (I think), even though that is not a required behavior. A hash set will most likely return its elements in the same order every time until a rehash happens. That same order might as well be the order of insertion, depending on the implementation.
These behaviors can be consistent enough that it's hard to break the unit test, even if I actively try to, but not nearly consistent enough to just say 'meh, I guess this data structure is sorted enough' and call it a day.

My question is twofold:

- How to write code which is more easily testable in spite of
  accidental functionality?
- How to test code written without the above in mind in spite of accidental functionality?

For the first question, an approach that might work is to create a 3rd build type (additionally to the common DEBUG and RELEASE builds) which intentionally breaks every not-officially-supported behavior. Something like this is used for [Facebook's F14 datastructures](https://code.fb.com/developer-tools/f14/):

> To make sure code doesn’t take implicit dependencies on F14’s iteration order, we randomize it for debug builds.

But I'm also interested in other solutions, of course.

The second question is a tougher one, I believe. Depending on the exact task it might be possible to break the accidental functionality for a wide range of possible implementations at once, that's one way to go then. Or, specifically to SQL ordering, you can create a view like
`CREATE VIEW SomeView AS SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY RANDOM()`
and run all queries against it, instead of the original table.

But I'm not aware of a general solution.

**Runnable example**

Consider the following code:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> s;
    s.insert(3);
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(2);

    std::stringstream res;
    for (auto e : s) res << e;

    if (res.str() == "312") return 0;  // Test passed.
    else return -1;  // Test failed.
}
```

Using MSVC++ 2017, this test passes every single time. The problem is, this, of course, does not mean I can rely on `unordered_set` secretly being ordered, because that functionality is **not** standard mandated, but completely accidental, and might or might not break with the next inserted value.

Comment: You've got written requirements, right?  Right?  If you need that functionality, then write a requirement for it.  If you don't need it, then leave it alone.  [The term "required but accidental" reminds of "it's optional, and it's also mandatory".]

Comment: **There's no such thing as accidental functionality.**  Unit tests don't fail just because you've added a new requirement.  Quite the opposite in fact: the only reason an existing unit test would fail is if *you've changed an existing requirement.*

Comment: So either your new ordering is optional (so why test it?), or it is required, in which case it is a new requirement with new tests, or it is a change in an existing requirement, so you fix your existing tests.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't think it's similar to 'optional but mandatory'. Required kind of means mandatory, of course. But my 'accidental' does not mean 'optional' in any way. It just means I accidentally already implemented the mandatory feature.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, I don't understand your comments. My problem is that my unit tests are not gonna fail. If I insert  values 1, 2, 3, into SomeTable then select * from SomeTable is gonna return 1, 2, 3 in this order, no matter what I do, until it suddenly breaks in production, because this is not a guaranteed behavior. I don't think I can explain it in more detail in a comment, but I think my original question elaborates.

Comment: That's because you haven't added a test that checks for that particular condition.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But what if I do? It's gonna pass, because every DB I am familiar with gonna return records in the order of insertion. I cannot change this behavior. But I also cannot rely on this 'ordering' in production, because this is not standard guaranteed behavior, but an implementation detail, or 'undocumented feature' if you wish.

Comment: There is a term "undocumented functionality".  I'm in business since 1999.  Doing high work for medical device industry since 2002 (high reliability, much requirements and testing).  I've never heard a term "accidental functionality".  Somebody must have mentioned "accidental functionality" for the purposes of humor.  Others didn't get the joke.  I wonder what we're going to have next: "collateral functionality"?..

Comment: You can only deal with this sort of "undocumented functionality" when you encounter it.  Your question more or less amounts to "how can I predict the unpredictable?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see how this could be the case. My question already does describe a possible (and industry tested) solution, and I doubt Facebook invented it through divination.

Comment: The same as you would do with non-accidental functionality.

Comment: Facebook invented it because they needed it to solve a problem.  Don't try to solve problems that don't exist yet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank for your advice, but I'm very intrigued by this problem nonetheless. I've just added some runnable example code, I'd greatly appreciate if you considered reopening the question, or giving some pointers how to further improve it, for everyone's benefit.

Comment: You need two tests to prove your example code works: one with ordered data as input, the other with unordered data.  Your code will only "accidentally" produce an ordered set if you provide it an ordered set as input.

Comment: You mean sorted, but that is not what I am talking about. What I mean that the order of insertion is preserved. Inserting 3, 1, 2 and retrieving 3, 1, 2 is just as problematic. I cannot rely on this behavior, because a unordered_set does not even give this much guarantee, but I also cannot catch this in a unit test, because this non-guaranteed behavior happens every time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you, I see you changed the close reason from 'unclear' to 'too broad'. Can you please give me some guidance how to make my question more specific? I asked 2 closely related questions, for one of them the facebook devblog provides a one sentence answer, and for the other one my SQL example shows that it's possible to add a wrapper around the 3rd party logic and use the first approach, and Hans-Martin Mosner proposes another approach.
These 3 things together are either the definitive answer, or if we missed something that can be shown in a new answer, in a definitive manner.

Comment: @szmate1618: I think there are some really good questions hidden in your post - but in the current form, I have to agree to Robert Harvey, the question is IMHO too broad. It seems you are mixing at least two different problems here: testing a component which fulfills already some previously undefined requirement using TDD style, which means you want to write a breaking test first. And second: testing that code does not *rely* on some undocumented feature of another component. I guess you should not mix up these questions, better ask them separately.

Comment: ... and your example makes your question not really clearer, because it introduces a different problem: components which fulfill a certain requirement only for the small data sets usually used in unit tests. I think there is a high chance that for many implementations of `unordered_set`, this example test will break when you use 300 integers instead of 3.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the feedback. It's possible to that I mix 2 separate issues, I will spend some time later this day to think this through.

Comment: @DocBrown As for my example, you do have a point, but it's part of the reason I didn't provide a concrete code example originally. No matter what concrete example I pick, you can correctly point out that this implementation only passes because your test doesn't cover X'. But the problem and the core of my question is that you can only tell what X is once you pinned down a specific implementation. For hash sets, X might be inserting 300 elements, but for databases it might be 3 billion, or more, or running some kind of defragmentation.

Comment: @szmate1618: yes, and that's exactly the reason why your question is too broad: you try to ask a general question for which there is probably no easy general answer. You need to pin down this to a concrete component first, ideally taken from a non-hypothetical real-world problem, then the question will become answerable.

Comment: @DavidArno: I agree to you the above post contains the basis of some really good question**s**, and the 6 downvotes are quite unjustified. Still I think the question is in the current form is too broad (see my former comments).

Comment: The short answer to what I've found to be the best way to handle this situation is to still write that failing test. So for example, if you are sure that the order is already consistent, write a test that checks for variation in order. When that fails, you can then change the test to check for preserved order. At that point, the test should pass. By failing it first, you get confidence that your test is checking the right thing.

Comment: `...What I mean that the order of insertion is preserved. Inserting 3, 1, 2 and retrieving 3, 1, 2 is just as problematic. I cannot rely on this behavior, because a unordered_set does not even give this much guarantee, but I also cannot catch this in a unit test, because this non-guaranteed behavior happens every time.` -- It would seem that you misunderstand the purpose of unit tests.  *You can't conclusively prove that non-trivial code works under every possible operating condition.*  Unit tests provide confidence that your code works, but not proof.

Comment: Going back to your database example, you already stated that most databases return records in insertion order, but do not guarantee that order so you can't rely on it.  Do you know what that means?  It means that *you can't rely on the return order of records from a database unless you include an ORDER BY clause.*  If a software developer or user is relying on that order in spite of the fact that the specifications already tell them they cannot, that is not "accidental functionality," it is ***pilot error.***

Comment: I'm fine with calling it a pilot error, but that does not answer how to catch such errors with unit tests.

Comment: How do you catch developers relying on an undocumented feature by writing  unit tests?  It's not possible.  The number of such undocumented features is potentially unlimited, and you can't test for them if you don't know about them (that's what "undocumented" means).

Comment: I find it strange how you marked my question as 'too broad' then answered it in a single sentence.

Comment: Oh, no.  The real answer would fill several books.  You don't solve this with unit tests, you solve it with better programming techniques that reduce the risks.  You solve it with better education and experience.  You stop doing things like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/391183/).

Comment: Also, my question already mentions at least 1 battle-tested approach, so I don't think I would accept 'it's impossible' as the correct answer.

Comment: You still have to understand the problem first.  You can't test what you don't know about.

Comment: @szmate1618: your question mentions one "battle-tested approach" for one specific issue of one specific component (and the approach requires a modification of the component itself, which is often not possible). But you asked the question in a very general manner (and mixing other aspects into it, as I wrote). So we could only try to give a list of examples and different solutions to these examples. This could fill a whole book - which makes your question too broad for the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: ... a way more focussed question would be: lets assume you have a piece of code relying on the behaviour of `unordered_set` you scetched above. Is it possible to use unit tests to stop devs from doing so? Why not? Is there a different testing technique which would work more in a more reliable fashion?

Comment: @Doc Brown, as I said, 'too broad' is a criticism I can easily accept. I think restricting it to a specific hash set implementation might be a bit too much, but restricting to hash sets in general is not unreasonable. But then I'll need to ask a separate question for SQL databases and an other one for NoSQL databases, since I'm curious about those as well. Surely, they won't be marked as duplicates?

Comment: @szmate1618: well I would start with one question and see what kind of answers you get. If you think they will fit to those other cases, you don't need to ask more. If they don't fit, it is unlikely a new question will be closed as a dupe since it requires a different solution.

Comment: @DavidArno  The question also has to be clear to remain open.  I guess, that [this comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/391139/how-to-test-required-but-accidental-functionality#comment860968_391139) is where the actual question got crystallized.  It took about 20 comments over a course of 18 hours to get to that point.

Comment: @NickAlexeev with all due respect, at that point my question already contained a specific example, linked an other very specific one, and Hans-Martin Mosner had posted an answer that 4 people found valuable enough to upvote. I feel like it must have taken quite a bit of conscious effort to misunderstand what I meant.

Comment: @szmate1618  This is (?) your actual question: "how to catch such errors [accidental use of facilities which aren't allowed by the requirements of the project, N.A.] with unit tests" (from [this comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/391139/how-to-test-required-but-accidental-functionality#comment860968_391139)).  Hans answered a different question.  That's how unclear you original questions was.

Comment: If he answered a different question then why did I +1 his answer? I think you are riding this horse backwards.

Comment: To quote John Tukey: "I'd rather have an approximate answer to the right question, than an exact answer to the wrong question."

Comment: @DavidArno  I flagged this question as unclear yesterday.  It wasn't clear.  Maybe language or terminology barrier got in the way.  But that doesn't mean that a questions shouldn't be flagged as unclear.

Comment: @DavidArno: the question, as it is written, is unclear, too broad, and ambigous (did you not read my comments above?). And as long as the OP does not edit it, stripping the ambigous parts out of it (which is probably >50% of the text) and makes it more focussed, I would not expect to get it reopened.

Comment: @DocBrown, I read it, understood it as I've had personal experience of this stuff and could have provided a useful answer. So I'd suggest that folk are confusing "the question is unclear" with "I don't understand this question". And no, I didn't read you comment. I read the first two comments, noted that they are both aggressive and completely misunderstand the question, and ignored the rest of the comments.

Comment: @DavidArno: Meta is the place to go if you want to grouse.

Comment: @DavidArno: The question has been reopened.  Post an answer, if you're still so inclined.

Comment: @DavidArno: comments critizing other people will often get deleted here by the mods, it does not matter if the person you critized is a mod himself or someone else (and I am fine with that). Whenever it happened to me, I took it as a lesson in learning how to write critics in a way it does not sound personal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you. Answer posted.

Comment: Databases don’t return rows in insertion order by accident, they return rows in clustered key order by accident.  If you want to change the order without adding an order by, change the clustered index.  You can also not have a clustered index and join with a table that does.  Or simplest of all, make the clustered index order by descending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1: Handling "accidental functionality" when writing tests**

To answer your question, let's start at the beginning: with a failing test. I'm going to take as read the idea that you already understand the principles of TDD and use it. So I can use a completely contrived and pointless example to focus on the issues you are asking about, rather than "selling" TDD itself.

I have a requirement: write a function that can take two numbers between 0 and 10 and return the sum of those numbers. I'm going to use C# here as it's what I'm most used to writing, but the ideas apply to all languages. I write my first test:

```
[Test]
For0And0_ResultIsZero()
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(0, 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
}

uint MyAddFunction() => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

The test fails. I threw an exception rather than returning 0. I fix the function:

```
uint MyAddFunction(uint a, uint b) => 0;
```

and my test passes. Great. Now for another test:

```
[Test]
For1And0_ResultIs1()
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(1, 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
}
```

The test fails, so I modify the function to make both tests pass:

```
uint MyAddFunction(uint a, uint b) => a == 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

And both tests pass. But the code is less than ideal. I want to refactor it to:

```
uint MyAddFunction(uint a, uint b) => a + b;
```

But I have a problem if I do. My tests will still pass, but so will a test that I subsequently add that tests any of the other combinations. We have an example of that "accidental functionality" that you were talking about. How do I write a failing test after performing the refactor?

There are two approaches we can take here. One is really useful during initial development when you arrive at this position. The other is more useful for when 
you are maintaining or enhancing an existing piece of code.

The first approach uses a technique called [recycling TDD](http://claysnow.co.uk/recycling-tests-in-tdd/). The idea being a simple one. To test those 121 combinations, you do not have to write 121 tests as there is nothing sacrosanct about a test. You are free to change an existing test to cover new functionality. In doing so, it must still fail once more though. In other words, there's no need to write a *new* failing test; make an existing one fail if that's more useful. So let's change that first test to:

```
[Test]
ForAllValuesOfXAnd0_ResultIsX([Range(0, 10)]uint x)
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(x, 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(x, result);
}
```

And it should fail for `x` of 2-10. Then we make it pass:

```
uint MyAddFunction(uint a, uint b) => a;
```

And finally, change the test once more to what we really want it to be:

```
[Test]
ForAllValuesOfXAndY_ResultIsXPlusY([Range(0, 10)]uint x, [Range(0, 10)]uint y)
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(x, y);
    Assert.AreEqual(x + y, result);
}
```

Again the test fails for all values of `y` save `0`. And we can write than function to make it pass:

```
uint MyAddFunction(uint a, uint b) => a + b;
```

So we've avoided that accidental functionality, without going insane through writing ever more tests and ever more convoluted code that only passes those tests and nothing else.

For the other approach, let's say our requirements change and we now need to handle 0-11. I'm fairly sure that my existing code will handle that. So I write a test to check:

```
[Test]
ForAllValuesOfXAnd11_ResultIsXPlus11([Range(0, 10)]uint x)
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(x, 10);
    Assert.AreEqual(x + 10, result);
}
```

Yes, the test passes. 11 is supported. But hand on, I've not actually tested 11; I tested 10. My test passed, but I didn't test what I meant to test. I broke the red/green rule by not writing a failing test first. But how can I write a failing test when it already supports adding 11? By writing the test to specifically fail on those new values:

```
[Test]
ForAllValuesOfXAndY_ResultIsXPlusY([Range(0, 11)]uint x, [Range(0, 11)]uint y)
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(x, y);
    Assert.IsTrue(result <= 20);
}
```

Now I have a test that passes all previous 0-10 tests, but fails for 10+11, 11+10 and 11+11. I've forced a failure for my new cases. And now I can change it to the proper test:

```
[Test]
ForAllValuesOfXAndY_ResultIsXPlusY([Range(0, 11)]uint x, [Range(0, 11)]uint y)
{
    var result = MyAddFunction(x, y);
    Assert.AreEqual(x + y, result);
}
```

**Part 2: Handling "accidental functionality" in implementation details**

In your example, you cite the case of having a hash set under the hood. You may have access to the source for that hash set and you look at it and confirm to yourself that it will indeed *always* return the elements in the order they were added. The author may even have stated that in the documentation. With that knowledge, you could just accept that your code works as is and all is well.

But what if it's not documented that way and the author changes the algorithm in the next release or a bug is introduced and it doesn't work as documented in the next release? Since you are adding it as a requirement to your code, maybe you should add a test for it?

There's no right answer here. Adding the test is arguably over-engineering and testing 3rd party code rather than your own (which unit tests should avoid). But if it isn't documented other than in the implementation code, a newer version could indeed change things so a unit test could be a useful early warning signal.

If you do decide to test it, don't forget to write a deliberately failing test first though. Think about your test data as you want to avoid repeating values for example and you want to minimise the impact that that accidental functionality has on your testing. So maybe test that `get_all().reverse()` *doesn't* return a matching set to get that failing test. Then remove the `.reverse()` to have the test pass to give you confidence in your new test.

**Part 3: Handling apparent accidental functionality due to "happy path testing"**

You also cite the example of having a SQL database under the hood. In this case, you might write an integration test that creates a database, writes some data and then reads it back without an `ORDER BY` and the test passes: we got the results back in the same order. So there's no need to add ordering to your `get_all()`; it does it already. Or does it?

Let's say you are using a SQL database implementation that I wrote (in my imagination only). Now the way I've implemented things is that I make all rows the same size in the file I store the table in. When a row is deleted, I set a deleted flag on that row. When you do another add, I look for a deleted row and re-use it if possible.

So one day, you add `delete` to your container class. And folk start complaining that your `get-all()` doesn't work properly after a delete. Your test for some `insert()`'s and then a `get_all()` took the happy path through my SQL implementation and so only *appeared* to work without that `ORDER BY`. When the system under the hood is sufficiently complex, you take a big risk by writing a simple unit test and coding around those results. If the SQL docs say that the order isn't guaranteed, play safe and add that `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, your issue is with an implementation that most of the time "accidentally" fulfills the requirement. This is something that is very hard to test. Successful tests only prove that the implementation does the right thing in the specific test case, they cannot prove that it will always behave correctly.

You normally don't reach this situation by deliberately changing the requirements such that a behavior that was formerly an unintended side effect of the implementation becomes a requirement.

In my experience, it is more common that the implementation is slightly buggy, does the right thing most of the time, so tests don't detect the bugs. Such bugs typically appear in production, and after debugging you know what the bug is. Ideally, you have also learned how to provoke the bug in the initial implementation, and you use that knowledge to write a regression test.

Of course you can do the same thing when you elevate an incidental behavior to the status of a requirement. It might be harder to construct a test case that would break the initial implementation if you have no actual incident in which the bug is provoked, but if you know the implementation details you might be able to find a way, for example by forcing a rehash.

But even if you can construct such a regression test, you should be aware that absence of proof of a bug is not proof of absence of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To continue off of what @Hans said, you can't reasonably tests every situation for this ordering issue and it might be buggy on certain situations.

But there is something you can do, you could put an assert in main code to make sure it is "in order", if it is not too expensive. There are certain situations where this is acceptable, e.g. if the list is not "in order" you wanted and that disorder is not an acceptable state for your program to keep running, so throwing an exception would be a good way to find out in prod what list insertion orders don't work, and then you can remedy this. It depends on your requirements and if this is acceptable behavior