# What is the proper way to unspecify an integer's value in C++?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, variables, initialization, setters

```cpp
// Default initialization
int i;    // i has an unspecified value
return i; // Probably 0, but Unreliable
i = 5;    // i has a specified value
i = int();// This will give it a specified value, 0
i = int{};// This will give it a specified value, 0
return i; // Reliable, no good!
int j;    // Workaround, obvious performance penalties
i = j;    // Also seems a bit too verbose, making code unreadable. 
i = *new int; // Doesn't seem like a good idea.
```

What's the proper way to unspecify `i`, or unassign its value, and make it unreliable again?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Why would you ever want to do that? You also seem to misunderstand what Undefined Behavior means. "obvious performance penalties" is completely wrong; since you're provoking UB, you can't predict anything.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It makes sense. How do you set `i` back to to its initial state, `int i;`? And obvious performance penalties because I will have to create a new object, potentially seriously taxing my algorithm.

Comment: "How do you return I to its initial state, int i;?" - Again, why? "I will have to create a new object" - You assume that declaring an int local variable does anything whatsoever in the compiled code. You're wrong.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I told you why. I want an unreliable return value. As to declaring a local variable, it depends on the compiler and what you do with the variable, does it not?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me either.

Comment: "I want an unreliable return value." - You can't. Using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, not "an unreliable value". Call `rand()` or the full RNG machinery if you want something unreliable. "As to declaring a local variable, it depends on the compiler and what you do with the variable, does it not?" - Yes, of course; my point is that your assumption of performance penalty is wrong.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The reason I did not call it `undefined behaviour`, was that it technically was defined, but rather you could not rely on the value. The reason why I don't call `rand()` is because I am not looking for a random value. `int i;`'s value is not a coin toss, but rather a value with a very peculiar and certain disposition.

Comment: What do you need that special value for, then? While it is technically true that having an uninitialized value around is not UB per se, doing any sort of branching on it *is* UB, and eventually pretty much every use of the value will lead to some kind of branching; unless you simply write it to some external device.

Comment: @Akiva, would it be acceptable if the program displays a rude message during important demos? Because that is also behavior that you could get from using an uninitialized value (especially if you run your program on a DS9000)

Comment: A compiler is free to assume `int i; return i;` is unreachable, and anything that transitively calls it is similarly unreachable, and eliminate it as dead code. The end result being a program equivalent to `int main() {}`

Comment: @SebastianRedl as explained, I need to return the same state of an unreliable value not dissimilar to the initial `int i;`, which is why a random value does not work. The other functions expecting this value, expect this unreliable state. I see what you mean about UB, but that only applies if I am not expecting it.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is not "we don't know the value here", it can include "there is no value, nor anything dependant on it", or exhibit "impossible" behaviour

Comment: @Caleth Isn't there technically always a value though?

Comment: [No](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: @Akiva: http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/DeathStation-9000. Undefined behavior does not mean the values are unpredictable, but that literally anything can happen.

Comment: "as explained, I need to return the same state of an unreliable value not dissimilar to the initial int i;" - While you have explained that multiple times, you still have not answered the underlying *why*. You are trying to do something that's not possible, and that usually means you're dealing with an XY problem.

Comment: [You rent a hotel room. You put a book in the top drawer of the bedside table and go to sleep. You check out the next morning, but "forget" to give back your key. You steal the key!

A week later, you return to the hotel, do not check in, sneak into your old room with your stolen key, and look in the drawer. Your book is still there. Astonishing!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794)

Comment: @SebastianRedl But the underlying `why`, implicit given the tags and the stackexchange chosen, is to adopt the proper industry standard for this coding paradigm. While I can achieve the desired state straightforwardly enough by something like `i = *new int;`, albeit it is a heap state as opposed to a stack state, the actual goal here is to achieve the FUNDAMENTAL state WITHOUT violating sane coding practices, in this case, a vicious memory leak. And yet you think I am asking how to debug my code so solve my specific issue. While that is a tertiary issue, it belongs on SO. Here, I need theory.

Comment: "is to adopt the proper industry standard for this coding paradigm." - The proper industry standard is **not to do it**. There, question answered.

Comment: @SebastianRedl There is no need to be contrarian for contrarian's sake. If I have to do it, which I do in order to achieve my end goal, then according to the industry standard, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: There is no industry standard for writing bugs. Tell me your end goal and maybe I can help.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Oh no, this is embarrassing. Sorry I should have been clearer. *I am not trying to fix a bug here*, because I actually am looking to return the unspecified value. I know what you mean though, because usually that is a common bug that people experience, but in this case I actually need to do it (return the unspecified value, not create a bug ;p), I just do not know the proper way to go about it at least according to industry or c++ standards. Again, this is not a bug I am trying to solve. This is by design.

Comment: @Akiva I never thought you're trying to fix a bug. I want to understand the design that leads to such a requirement. Because I'm 99.9% sure that whatever your goal is, you won't achieve it by invoking UB.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Okay, but now you have me a little bit confused. I am not trying to **"write a bug"** either if that is what you meant. Like I said, this is by design. I am not trying to sabotage any code here, or create a security flaw, or anything like that.

Comment: @Akiva You're not trying to write a bug, but it's what you're doing if you access an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Look I already addressed that. I know that `i = *new int;` is a buggy way of achieving this; I only included it within my example code to demonstrate that while I could get a desired state, it would be at the cost of a memory leak. I was not actually suggesting I do this.

Comment: @SebastianRedl unless you mean the solution in pschill's answer, which there too, I would completely agree that what he is effectively doing is writing a bug. I want to know the proper way to get the state without writing a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93071/discussion-between-sebastian-redl-and-akiva).

Comment: @SebastianRedl: What would be the proper way of informing a compiler that all possible behaviors that would result from any bit pattern an object holds would be equally acceptable, and consequently any preceding writes to that object's storage on the current code path are irrelevant and may be omitted if not needed on any other code path?  That sounds like something that any language interested in facilitating optimization should include, but neither C nor C++ does.

Comment: @supercat If you don't want a write on some code path, don't do the write on that code path. If you don't care for the value of a variable on some code path, don't read it. Can you elaborate more what you want to actually achieve? Maybe link a code snippet with some comments that describe desired behavior?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: As a simple example, a function may specify that its output buffer will only be meaningful if its return value indicates that a loop completed successfully.  If the loop could exit early without having written later portions of the buffer, a compiler would not be allowed to process later iterations until earlier operations can be proven successful.  If the function were to end with `if (error) __SET_UNSPECIFIED_ARRAY(outputBuff, numberOfElements);`, however then a compiler could generate code to perform multiple iterations of the loop in parallel.

Comment: @supercat Interesting idea. So basically, because the compiler must assume that the previous contents of a buffer might be meaningful, it can't overwrite it speculatively? And you want to tell it that it actually can do that? I don't think there's a way to express this in C++. That would make for a good question though, a possibly X to the Y question this one is.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Many programs in many application fields need to perform calculations that may turn out to be meaningless, either because they can't tell in advance whether something will happen that will render them meaningless, or because performing calculations unconditionally is cheaper than the calculations necessary to determine whether they're needed.  Letting programmers invite optimizations in cases where loosely-defined behavior is adequate, but jumping the rails would be unacceptable, will allow many more optimizations than will be possible...

Comment: ...if the only choices are fully-defined behavior or jumping the rails.  I wish those in charge of the language would recognize that trying to use UB as a basis for things like dead branch elimination is in just about every way inferior to adding directives to indicate when precise semantics are and are not needed.

Comment: @supercat "where loosely-defined behavior is adequate" - But the behavior in your example wouldn't be loosely defined. It would be strictly defined as "accessing this memory is UB unless the function returned success". - "trying to use UB as a basis for things like dead branch elimination is in just about every way inferior to adding directives" - Those don't look like mutually exclusive options to me.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: What I called for was not Undefined Behavior, but rather "...informing a compiler that all possible behaviors that would result from any bit pattern an object holds would be equally acceptable, and consequently any preceding writes to that object's storage on the current code path are irrelevant and may be omitted if not needed on any other code path?"  Requiring that programmers include code to systematically avoid accessing such values would force them to block the useful optimizations that the constructs were supposed to facilitate.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Reading an object whose bit pattern is Unspecified yields UB has trap representations, but otherwise simply yields an Unspecified value represented by that bit pattern. Implementations are allowed to have trap representations on any non-character primitives, but many specify that they *don't*.  Some implementations use a larger storage formats for objects whose address is taken from those whose address isn't, and may have trap representations for the latter even if they don't for the former, and some optimizations would require recognizing a concept of non-deterministic...

Comment: ...values (as opposed to merely Unspecified) but such optimizations will only be useful if there's a way for code to safely access possibly-non-deterministic values.

Answer (score 2):

I don`t see any point in doing this, but you could just copy the value of another uninitialized integer:

```
void uninitialize(int& x)
{
    int a;
    x = a;
}
```

You should also be aware that reading the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. Compilers may do something meaningful here, but they are not required to.

Many compilers just reuse existing memory for `a`, which means that `a` may contain bytes of sensitive data. This function should not be used if you care about security (which you should).

Comment: Very nice solution, though one picks a prior stack value, which - as a real unitialized variable - exposes a bit of possibly sensitive data.

Comment: @JoopEggen Agreed. This solution while novel, has some security concerns.

Comment: @JoopEggen I agree and added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = (int) (rand() * 10E9); // Some random value.
```

In contrast to JavaScript, there is no unitialized/undefined value. As soon as the variable walks out of scope it's primitive value is lost.

One sometimes sees a zeroing or such in security relevant contexts, nulling secret values.

Comment: That is giving me a random value completely dissimilar to the value proclivity of `int i;`.

Comment: An unitialized variable will point to somewhere in memory where anything can be visible, the remains of old variables or whatever. This is especially yummy for a `char*`. The only purpose of a reunitialisation is to have garbage in the variable. If you want to have some unitialized state of a variable, maybe use `optional<int>`. Or store the original value: `int i; int bah = i; ....; i = bah;`